# Terraform how to remove key from resource when variable is empty?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform resource definition as such:

```
variable "NUM_NODES" {
   type = number
}

resource "aws_resource" {
   num_nodes = var.NUM_NODES
}
```

There is a restriction on the resource for num_nodes, if present, to not be empty. Is there a way for terraform to ignore keys without values on the "aws_resource"? So the key num_nodes is not included at all?

If this isn't possible what is the best option? Can anyone help me?

I've tried to set the default of NUM_NODES to null

```
variable "NUM_NODES" {
  type = number
  default = null
}
```

but continue to see errors regarding 'invalid value for input variable', instead of it being ignored

Comment: You asked three different questions in this question, and I would speculate that you really meant to ask one. My best guess is that your question is how to force the value of `var.NUM_NODES` to never be `null`. Is that correct, or what is the question otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

When defining the arguments in a `resource` block that are declared by the provider itself, setting an argument to `null` is exactly the same as not setting it at all.

It should therefore work to declare a variable as optional by setting its default to `null`, and then assign the value directly to the argument:

```
# NOTE: It's conventional to name Terraform variables in lowercase
variable "node_count" {
  type    = number
  default = null
}

resource "example" "example" {
  num_nodes = var.node_count
}
```

There is no way for a provider to distinguish between an argument being unset completely vs. being set to null because the two are represented identically in the protocol that Terraform uses to talk to providers.

If you try this and see validation errors for the argument in question then there must be something else going on that isn't reflected in this example. For example, if you actually *set* `node_count` in the calling `module` block then the default value of `null` won't be used and so it'll be up to the calling module to provide a valid value for this argument, or to explicitly set it to `null`.